# interpolating an attribute value in an Angular template causes a parse error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

I am getting the error: angular.js:10627 Error: [$parse:syntax]

when interpolating a value in the template, only when it's in the attribute of an element.

template field_message.html:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="{{ model }}">
<div>{{ model }}</div>
```

directive:

```
myApp.directive('ivInput', function(){
    return {

        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: "field_message.html",
        scope: {
            model: '@ngModel'
        }


    };
});
```

view html:

```
<div iv-input="flatK" ng-model="modelname"></div>
```

In the template, the first instance of {{ model }} causes a parse error. If I remove this, the other instance correctly renders out the model name. Is there a way to get the model name into the value for ng-model on the input element?

Comment: <input type="number" ng-model="model ">

Answer (score 0):

Working absolutely fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">




</head>

<body ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div iv-input="flatK" ng-model="modelname"></div>
  <span>{{modelname}}</span>

    <script>
      var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive('ivInput', function(){
    return {

        restrict: 'EA',
        template: "<input type='number' ng-model='ngModel'>"+
"<div>{{ model }}</div>",
        scope: {
            ngModel:'='
        }


    };
});
app.controller('ctrl',function($scope){
$scope.modelname=23;
} )
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```